# How to get all but last element outside of loop in Python

Tags: string, list

I have two problems with this code.

1. I need to get the string list calibration_values out of the loop so I can use them elsewhere in the program.
2. I need all of the elements in the string list except the last one. I am not able to use pop because this is a string and not a list. I am unable to use variable[:-1] because that truncates the last number by one digit instead of giving me all but the last element in the list. I thought maybe I needed to get the values out of the function for [:-1] to work but that takes me back to issue #1.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
def Parse_CSV(file, string):
    global cal_string
    global calibration_values
    cal_string = []
    calibration_values = []
    
    with open(file, "r") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        reader2 = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            for column in row:
                if string in column:
                    # print("Found search string:", string, "  in ", file," .Writing Calibration String\n")
                    cal_string = row
                    calibration_values = cal_string[1]
                    print(calibration_values)
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "get out of the loop" - it's already declare out of the scope of the loop, so that should be fine. Do you mean "out of the Parse_CSV function"?

Comment: I think we need more high-level context on what you're trying to do.